# Android:Failed to resolve dependency in android studio

Tags: android, github, gradle, build.gradle, couchbase

I am using the Android Studio 1.4 and i am developing application
    where i need to store data into Couchbase Lite.
    I am adding dependency as follows in app level build.gradle
        compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.0.2'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.couchbase.examples.couchdb"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.0.2'
}
```

and the code bellow is of another build.grade where i have added the following code:

```
 repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/"
        }
```

But the problem is that i am getting error when i clicked on "Sync project with gradle file option" in android studio. The error is:

```
Failed to resolve:com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.0.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Failed to resolve:com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.0.2

This issue happens because

```
compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.0.2'
```

**doesn't exist** on jcenter repo.
You can check [this link](https://bintray.com/couchbase/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/view).

Currently the only **version is 1.1.0.**

Just use:

```
compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.1.0'
```

Comment: when we add this dependency and run application it downloads all files needed to run couchDB so by default which Edition is downloaded 1)community Edition 2)Enterprise Edition

Comment: i am confused among these and i want to use Community Edition

Answer (score 1):

I have correctly installed couchbase lib by following the next steps :

1. Remove the extra repository line (the maven code), this means your repository code has to be like:

   ```
   repositories {    
       jcenter()    
   }
   ```
2. Change your couchbase compile line with this one:

   ```
   compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.+'
   ```

It tells gradle  (the  '.+' thing ) to always grab the latest version.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: extra repository line the code used to give url ?please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: modified answer to give a clearer idea of what it should look like

Comment: tnx i will let you know about status